# What is the meaning of $G/cm^2$?

Tags: units, magnetic-fields

I'll prefix this question by stating that I am not a physicist, I am a programmer. I am working on updating a (very old) program that calculates the performance of a magnet. This whole program is in CGS units and it is required of me to change it to SI units.

A particular equation in this program gives the Gauss/square centimeter. I understand this as the gauss going through a 1 square centimeter area.

Is there a proper name for the unit of $\frac{G}{cm^2}$?, the closest I can find in CGS terms in a Maxwell unit which is $G \cdot cm^2$

It's less about the name of the unit and more about being able to check whether this empirically derived equation is correct.

Unfortunately I cannot post this equation as I do not have the necessary permissons.

---

In the comments it has now been shown that
$$\frac{G}{cm^2} = \frac{T}{m^2}$$

So the question now becomes, what does this mean? The field strength in an area?

Comment: You can share the equation by using Latex, without it, there is not anything we can tell from just units.

Comment: It may be tedious, but you really need to communicate this equation to us somehow.

Comment: @DavidH I'll try, I cannot post it straight out because it gives the company I'm working for a commercial edge over their competitors.

Comment: The SI unit for magnetic field strength is the [Tesla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_%28unit%29) which is $10^4$ Gauss. In SI base units $1\ \mathrm{T} = 1\ \mathrm{kg\ s^{-2}\ A^{-1}}$. I can't think of a physical situation where $\text{field strength}/\text{area}$ is useful but $\text{field strength}\times\text{area}$ is the magnetic flux, with SI derived unit the Weber.

Comment: @MichaelBrown So $G/cm^2 = T/m^2$? If $1T = 10^{-4}G$ and $1 cm^2 = 10^{-4}m^2$ then $G/cm^2 = 10^{-4}T/10^{-4}m^2 = T/m^2$

Comment: Yeah that's right (except you mean $1T=10^{+4} G$, but the rest is right).

Comment: @MichaelBrown So I guess the question now becomes what does field strength/area mean?

Comment: I can't think of a useful meaning in terms of fundamental physics. Field strength is an "intensive" quantity meaning it doesn't scale with area or volume (i.e., it is more like pressure or density than force or mass). So the interpretation probably rests on the secret details of whatever your application is. If you can reduce the problem to a "toy" form that doesn't give away too much detail but at least explains what you need this for maybe we can help further.

Comment: If you had some circular fridge magnet, and you measured the magnetic field strength at some point, you could find the derivative of the field strength at that point with respect to the area of the magnet (with $dA=2 \pi r dr$, hence the "circle" restriction). That would have units of$G/cm^2$. I suppose a situation where such a thing might be useful from an engineering standpoint is imaginable!

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy That sounds correct! They use the this mystery calculation to determine the strength of a magnet at a certain height. There's another calculation which gives a value in the same units required to lift a ferrous cube/cuboid. If the magnet's mystery factor is >= that of the ferrous cube/cuboid then it can be said that it can lift that object.

Although these are up to 34 tonne electro magnets, not quite your fridge magnet :)